# Swift.Result gives error for generic parameter type in swift 5

Tags: swift, generics, alamofire, codable

Not sure why me getting below error in my below code. I hv written wrapper for alamofire using generics where response is of generic type.

[image]

Code :

```
public protocol NetworkCall {
    func requestmethod<T: Codable>(requestModel: RequestType, completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<T, ErrorModel>) -> Void)
}


public class RequestType : NSObject {

}

public class ErrorModel: Error {
    
}
```

Please suggest the correction in above code.

Comment: I can’t see that you pass the actual type anywhere

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - before passing ..it should compile, which does not happen

Comment: Why did you remove the code that doesn’t compile, the image is not easy to read? Note that T in requestMethod and in alamofireClassRequest are two completely separate types so the compiler need help to understand what T is for alamofireClassRequest and you don’t provide that info anywhere. You need to do something like `alamofireClassRequest(for: T.self, …)` (for better understanding it might be better to rename one of the 2 T to something else)